# C++ Using the function of the class two class above

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, interface

I have the current setup:

```
class Interface1
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface1() {}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Interface2 : public virtual Interface1
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface2() {}
    virtual void DoSomething() override = 0;
    virtual void DoSomethingElse() = 0;
};

class MyClass1 : public Interface1
{
  public:
    MyClass1();
    void DoSomething() override;
};

class MyClass2 : public Interface2
{
  public:
    MyClass2();
    void DoSomething() override;
    void DoSomethingElse() override;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, boost::any> items;
    items.insert(make_pair("item1", shared_ptr<Interface1>(new MyClass1())));
    items.insert(make_pair("item2", shared_ptr<Interface2>(new MyClass2())));

    auto object = items.at("item2");
    auto item = boost::any_cast<shared_ptr<Interface1>>(object);
    item->DoSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, nothing happens. `MyClass2` doesn't appear to be calling `DoSomething()`, which is what I would like. How can I make the call to `Interface1::DoSomething()` actually call `Interface2::DoSomething()`? I would think it would be possible because they all inherit from each other, but I can't seem to make it work.

The reason I want this is because I have some functions which will only work with classes inherited from `Interface2`, but some functions need to support classes derived from either `Interface1` and `Interface2`. Once boost::any takes over I loose which type it originally was, but it shouldn't be a problem if I could use the setup described above, so even if my original class was derived from `Interface2`, it could call the same function in `Interface1` and get the same result.

Is there a way of doing what I want with the current setup?

EDIT:
Sorry, the `void` in front of the constructors where my bad, but that is not the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you need the `boost::any`?

If you need to determine the difference between `Interface1` and `Interface2`, and you have a `std::shared_pointer` stored in your map, then just store a `std::shared_pointer<Interface1>` and use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Interface2>` to determine whether you have an `Interface1` or an `Interface2`

**Example:**

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Interface1
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface1() = default;
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Interface2 : public Interface1
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface2() = default;
    virtual void DoSomethingElse() = 0;
};

class MyClass1 : public Interface1
{
  public:
    MyClass1() {}
    void DoSomething()     override { std::cout << "\t\t" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};

class MyClass2 : public Interface2
{
  public:
    MyClass2() {}
    void DoSomething()     override { std::cout << "\t\t" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    void DoSomethingElse() override { std::cout << "\t\t" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Interface1>> items;

    items.emplace("item1", std::make_shared<MyClass1>());
    items.emplace("item2", std::make_shared<MyClass2>());

    auto check = [&items](const std::string& name)
        {
            auto object = items.at(name);
            auto item = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Interface2>(object);
            if (item)
            {
                std::cout << name << " is an Interface2\n";
                item->DoSomething();
                item->DoSomethingElse();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << name << " is an Interface1\n";
                object->DoSomething();
            }
        };

    check("item1");
    check("item2");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
item1 is an Interface1
        virtual void MyClass1::DoSomething()
item2 is an Interface2
        virtual void MyClass2::DoSomething()
        virtual void MyClass2::DoSomethingElse()
```

**Some final notes:**

- I also question the need for virtual inheritance between `Interface2` and `Interface1`
- I don't believe you need to override `DoSomething` in `Interface2` - it's already there by publically inheriting from `Interface1`

  `virtual void DoSomething() override = 0;` is unnecessary

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I require. I must come a bit longer to tell if this holds up, but right now it looks like it does. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not useful, but it works:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/695766d90ff1d47a)</kbd>**

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Interface1
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface1() {}
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Interface2 : public virtual Interface1
{
  public:
    virtual ~Interface2() {}
    virtual void DoSomething() override = 0;
    virtual void DoSomethingElse() = 0;
};

class MyClass1 : public Interface1
{
  public:
    MyClass1() {}
    void DoSomething() override { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

class MyClass2 : public Interface2
{
  public:
    MyClass2(){}
    void DoSomething() override { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
    void DoSomethingElse() override { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

#include <memory>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

int main()
{
    using std::shared_ptr;
    std::map<std::string, boost::any> items;
    items.insert(make_pair("item1", shared_ptr<Interface1>(new MyClass1())));
    items.insert(make_pair("item2", shared_ptr<Interface2>(new MyClass2())));

    {
        auto object = items.at("item1");
        auto item = boost::any_cast<shared_ptr<Interface1>>(object);
        item->DoSomething();
    }
    {
        auto object = items.at("item2");
        auto item = boost::any_cast<shared_ptr<Interface2>>(object);
        item->DoSomething();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
virtual void MyClass1::DoSomething()
virtual void MyClass2::DoSomething()
```

> #### Of course you need to cast to the correct interface

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Here are the correct definitions for `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` :

```
class MyClass1 : public Interface1
{
public:
     MyClass1();
    void DoSomething() override;
};

class MyClass2 : public Interface2
{
public:
    MyClass2();
    void DoSomething() override;
    void DoSomethingElse() override;
};
```

You have declared your constructors as `void MyClass1()`, which is illegal. The correct constructor syntax is `MyClass1()`.

I don't know which compiler you're using, but I'd throw it out for not raising a syntax error.

Comment: That's _not_ the problem. That's merely a sloppy sample.

Comment: @sehe: yes, that IS the problem. I've run the code and it works now.

Comment: Right. Look at my answer. I did /actually/ run the code. [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/695766d90ff1d47a)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe no that ISN'T the problem - you just fixed the constructor problem, but that wasn't what the OP was asking for help about.